# How do i open a page on top of a modal in ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a HomePage(main page) from which multiple modals are opened (modal1,modal2,modal3). On the last modal 'modal3', I have an ion-search with an ion-virtual-scroll to populate the results which will be show in a card.

Each of these card has an router-link attached to it.
Upon clicking on the card it should open a 'Page' which is associated with the id and present, but since its a page it does not show on top of the modal and is only visible once the modals are dismissed.

I have tried to follow the ion-nav from [here](https://ionicframework.com/blog/how-to-navigate-in-ionic-modals-with-ion-nav/) but I couldn't get it working and got me all confused.

Modal 3 Code...

```
<ion-virtual-scroll [items]="this.speclFun.questions" approxItemHeight="185px">
        <ion-card *virtualItem="let itemMod;" [routerLink]="['/main/user/tabs/home/view',itemMod.id]" (click)="openPage()">
          <ion-row>
            <ion-col size=" 12">
              <ion-card-header class="card-header">
                <ion-icon name="help-circle-outline" style="margin-right: 5px;"></ion-icon>
                <ion-label>{{ itemMod.title }}</ion-label>
              </ion-card-header>
            </ion-col>
          </ion-row>

          <ion-row>
```

Modal 3 typeScript:

```
      async openPage() {
    const modal = this.modalController.create({
      component: ModalBaseComponent,
      componentProps: {
        rootPage: AnswerPage
      }
    })
  }
```

Shared Components module is declared as an import in my homepage.module.ts file.

Shared-component module : [image: shared-component module]

modal-base component : [image: modal base comp]

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: I have made the changes to the question with code attached

Comment: I had a case similar to this, I ended up using the same page with custom made segments.(3 steps process where I guide the user through some actions in each "page"). If you don't mind changing your reasoning, let me know, I will post you my solution.

Comment: Please avoid posting screenshots of code, put your code between ` so it is more `readable and easy to use`